# ASP.NET Core Web API is not returning full object

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API returning `ReconResults`. The API for some reason is not sending me the messages part of the object. I see the values of the messages prior to leaving the API. I am sure I am missing something pretty dumb.

Model:

```
public class ReconResults
{
    public IEnumerable<int> ReconIds { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ReconErrorResults> Messages { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; }
}

public class ReconErrorResults
{
    int ErrNo { get; set; }
    string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Repo:

```
using (var connection = sqlProvider.GetConnection())
{
    var aresults = connection.QueryMultipleAsync("recon.usp_pro",
        parameters,
        commandTimeout: 1500,
        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).Result;

    results.Messages = await aresults.ReadAsync<ReconErrorResults>();
    results.ReconIds = await aresults.ReadAsync<int>();
    results.Success = (parameters.Get<int>("@Return") == 0 ? true : false);
}
```

Results

```
{
  "reconIds": [
    -1
  ],
  "messages": [
    {}
  ],
  "success": false
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `ReconErrorResults` properties should be marked as Public if you intend to use them outside the `ReconErrorResults` class...

```
public class ReconErrorResults
{
    public int ErrNo { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: haha. I knew I was going to embarrass myself on this one